# How to make Material UI icons show on the local host?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, web-development-server

I have tried this simple code to test the Material UI, when I save the code and run the local host browser it show empty white screen, if I removed the "" it shows the text  and the img

> 

```
import React from 'react';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
function Header(props) {
    return (
       <main>
       <div className="header">
            <h1>I am a header</h1>
            <AddIcon/>
            <img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b8/YouTube_Logo_2017.svg"
            alt="" />
        </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

I followed the steps on the Mui website to install the required packages but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying different solutions this is what worked for me:

- Create the react project using `npx create-react-app urprojname`
- `cd` to the created project folder
- open the terminal and run the 2 following lines to be able to use Material UI v5

```bash
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct by clicking the tick sign next to it